# Получения вывода командной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pyinstaller, ос

```
import os,subprocess
command=r'pyinstaller C:\Users\user\Desktop\Питон\hello_world.py'
output=os.popen(command)
print(output.read())
```

я хотел получить вывод командной строки,но метод возвращает лишь перевод строки('\n'):

```
>>>
```

Если вручную набрать эту команду в командной строке,то она выведет:

```
94 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
94 INFO: Python: 3.8.1
94 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
98 INFO: wrote C:\Users\user\hello_world.spec
99 INFO: UPX is not available.
102 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Питон', 'C:\\Users\\user']
102 INFO: checking Analysis
102 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
...
13823 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Именно этот вывод мне и нужен.Попробовал вариант с модулем subprocess,результат тот же:

```
output=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(output.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

```
>>>
```

Comment: [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: Довольно долго читал через разные ресурсы про этот метод,до сих пор плохо понимаю его.Непонятно зачем нужно передавать ему в качестве команды лист с аргументами.Некоторые команды получается выполнить,но не pyinstaller.Зато на "обочине" этой документации наткнулся на замечательный метод getoutput,который просто выполняет команду и возвращает вывод командной строки,но о нём,как ни странно,никто не говорит

Comment: Дайте ответ на собственный вопрос ниже, если он решён

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный текст поступает не на `stdout`, a на `stderr`.

`getoutput` сливает их в одно, поэтому работает.

Но `getoutput` лучше не использовать, т. к. он игнорирует код возврата.

Есть еще `check_output` и `getstatusoutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил с помощью метода getoutput:

```
output=subprocess.getoutput('pyinstaller C:/Users/user/Desktop/Питон/empty.py')
print(output)
```

Этот метод прямым образом возвращает вывод командной строки.